# What is the (co)limit of a Quiver?

Tags: limits-colimits, quiver

Given that a [Quiver](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/quiver) (also known as directed multigraphs) is so important in category theory, being that every Quiver produces a free Category, and every Category has an underlying Quiver, I was wondering what a limit of a Quiver is. (See also the nice overview of Quivers and Diagrams in the answer on [finding the limits of a diagram](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2617950/finding-the-limit-of-a-diagram/2618188#2618188))

So if I take a category with two objects E and V and two functions s,t: E → V which given the start and end edges of vertices, then I should be able to have a functor from that to sets, which determines a quiver. Then all I need is to add a constant functor to some object of set say $L$ - the putative limit - and then find the real one. So for each vertex of the diagram, $v$, we have an arrow $p_v:L\to D(v)$. In this case it would be  have the equations $p_V = s \circ p_E$,  $p_V = t \circ p_E$. Which leads to $s \circ p_E = t \circ p_E$.

What would the co-version be? I suppose we turn the arrows around 
$p_v: D(v) \to L$ giving us $p_E = p_V \circ s$ and $p_E = p_V \circ t$, and so $p_V \circ s = p_V \circ t$

(I'd like to also ask what Monad one could build with the Free and Underlying Functors, but I guess that should be a different question).

Comment: To be clear, you're just asking for the (co)limit of a functor from your two-object category to $\mathtt{Set}$?

Comment: Two object and two arrows. Two objects alone would give us (co)products.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Co)limits of this form are called *(co)equalizers*.  In sets, an equalizer of a functor $D$ from your category is just given by the set $L=\{x\in D(E): D(s)(x)=D(t)(x)\}$ with its inclusion map to $D(E)$.  (So, in terms of quivers, it is just the set of loops.)  Coequalizers are a bit more complicated, but a coequalizer can be constructed as the quotient of $D(V)$ by the smallest equivalence relation $\sim$ such that $D(s)(x)\sim D(t)(x)$ for all $x\in D(E)$.  (In terms of quivers, this quotient is the set of connected components of the quiver.)

Note that colloquially, one typically just speaks of the (co)equalizer of a pair of morphisms $f,g:A\to B$ in some category, without talking about a functor explicitly.  This refers to the (co)limit of the functor from your category which sends $E$ to $A$, $V$ to $B$, and $s$ and $t$ to $f$ and $g$.

Comment: Yes, that is quite neat. Having written down my question as above I was thinking this looked very much like (co)equalisers :-) Thinking about them in terms of quivers will I think make them more intuitive for me.

Comment: Interestingly this means that what corresponds to products here are looping arrows which are I suppose the most independent form of arrows, a bit like products bring two things together but in the most independent way (orthogonally). And co-products that are  disjoint unions  here correspond to groups of nodes that are somehow linked up, each group constituting such a disjoint set.